# Show or mark that a question has no upvoted answers in the question listing

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, question-lists

There's no visual difference in the question lists between those with upvoted answers and those with answers but not upvoted.

Currently, if a question has no answers at all, you see this:

[image: nothing in the oven]

If a question has one answer that has been upvoted at least once, you see this:

[image: question with answer upvoted at least once]

If a question has one answer that has *never* been upvoted, you see this:

[image: question with single un upvoted answer]

In other words, you can't tell if a question has likely been answered well vs. answered poorly/unknown.

This means that questions that still need attention (because either the existing answer deserves an upvote or a better answer is needed) don't stand out at all from questions that have an answer with at least one upvote.

If a question has one answer that has never been upvoted, you should see (something like) this:

[image: question with no answers upvoted]

Note: I'm not saying this is the best possible graphic, I just threw this together to get the idea across.

This will give questions with no upvotes a little bit more visibility while adding very little complexity to the UI.

Comment: you can already filter for questions-that-have-no-upvoted-answers; they're called *unanswered questions* and they have their own tab at the top of the page: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: @~quack, I was thinking "unanswered questions" meant questions with zero answers, but I guess it does include questions with non-upvoted answers as well. I still think it might be helpful to give a unique marking to questions with non-upvoted answers, though. I think that little bit of extra information would be appreciated in all question listings.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that a question has an answer with upvotes isn't an indication of whether the question has a good answer. If fact, even when a question has an upvoted, accepted answer, it doesn't mean it doesn't need attention. The answer may be wrong, or poorly worded, or missing some information.

More importantly, it's worth reading the question and answer to see if it needs attention in the form of votes - is the most useful answer at the top? If not, vote it up. Are other answers helpful, if so, vote them up. Is the question clearly written and likely to be useful to others, if so, vote it up.

Even more importantly, you might learn something by reading the question or the answers.

I'd discourage adding anything to the UI which might discourage users from reading questions.

Comment: I agree with your point that upvotes don't guarantee anything, but I think your ascribing way too much power to what I'm suggesting. If I suggested *hiding* questions with accepted answers or something, I would agree with you, but I'm just saying, give a little extra visibility to questions with no upvoted answers. I don't think my suggestion would discourage users from reading questions. What it might do is help readers looking to help someone out prioritize their reading a little bit better.

Comment: @DanM - Maybe - I know I am less likely to read a question which has the yellow number of answers in yellow (denoting an accepted answer). I wonder if you're ascribing too much power to that person who's given an answer an upvote. What do they know? They might know what they're talking about, but equally they might just like the answerer's name. The yellow accepted text is helpful to an extent (the OP's hopefully saying "no further help needed, I got what I wanted"), but I'm not sure that showing that someone somewhere think's something's worth an upvote would be a helpful measure.

Comment: I agree with you that there is nothing magic about an upvote, but I still think the odds are higher that a question with no upvoted answers has not been satisfactorily addressed than one that has upvoted answers. Also, as ~quack pointed out (see comment above), there is a whole page/filter (Unanswered Questions) dedicated to questions either with zero answers or with answers that were never upvoted, so StackOverflow already recognizes this distinction as useful. I'm just saying, it should be a distinction people should be able to spot more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I think, to be sightly simpler, if the question has one (or more) answers, none of them with a positive score, you should see a grey box (like 0 answers), but with a non-zero number.

Same number of visual styles, simply grouping the "not-positively-answered" questions in with the "not answered questions" in terms of the colour scheme.

Comment: +1, Yes, I actually prefer that to my suggested graphic.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are already too many color combinations. I usually just ignore the red/green box with the white/yellow number because I always have to think what it means.. Don't complicate it further!

Comment: agree! (and the 15 characters with me)