# Indication of whether any answers have upvotes in the question list

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, question-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show or mark that a question has no upvoted answers in the question listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42269/show-or-mark-that-a-question-has-no-upvoted-answers-in-the-question-listing)

I rarely bother to click through to questions in my Questions > Interesting section that already have answers, since I presume that the answers that are there will already be good enough, so it isn't worth my time adding my own answer.

I'm sure this isn't always true though, and it would be one stage better if I could see at least whether answers have upvotes (perhaps the green 'number-of-answers' colour could be paler / not present until answers have any upvotes).

Or would this be too expensive to implement, even if just for the interesting-questions lists, not the front page?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question has no accepted answer, it could be argued that unless it has a lot (more than 5?) of answers you should *always* look at it so see if you can add a better answer or improve and existing one regardless of the number of votes any of the answers have.

If there is no accepted answer then it means that the OP's problem hasn't been solved (unless they are new to the site and don't know how it works), so there is always room for more information.

Comment: Maybe I *should*, but I tend not to. I'm not really sure why, because I know that lots of those could be improved. Perhaps it's because in my experience it's easiest to maximise (utility (aka rep))/(time spent answering questions) by answering the set of questions where I'm the first of the interested answer-ers to answer.

Comment: @Autopulated - that's fair comment - I am playing devil's advocate here.