# Styling of 'number of answers'

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show or mark that a question has no upvoted answers in the question listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42269/show-or-mark-that-a-question-has-no-upvoted-answers-in-the-question-listing)

On all SE sites, in any question list, there are separate stylings for:

- Questions with 0 answers (usually default styling--red on SO)
- Questions with answers (a green box on SO, a green number on physics.SE)
- Questions with accepted answers (usually a little decoration on the previous point. On SO, the text turns yellow, on P.SE it gets a green box)

The issue is that people tend to ignore questions that already have an answer. So, while browsing the questions, they have no way of knowing if a question has a *good* answer, so even for a question with a downvoted answer, they may assume that it has an answer, and might skip it. I propose a simple change (may not be simple as each site will have to update its CSS differently):

Add separate styling for these two cases--

- Highest voted answer has 0 upvotes
- All answers are downvoted

As @ShaDowWizArd pointed out, too many colors is a bad thing. What if all questions with no upvoted answers were styled the same as questions with 0 answers? After all, from the questions list one can easily see if the question has 0 answers, but not if it has upvoted answers.
Comments?

Comment: *"people tend to ignore questions that already have an answer"* `[citation-needed]`

Comment: @CodyGray At least, that's what I've noticed after going through physics.SE's old unanswered(unaccepted) questions. Quite a few have a zero-voted answer which is wrong.

Comment: I don't think such thing is necessary - too many colors are not good idea IMO. People should assume that as long as there's no accepted answer it means they can try their luck and add their own answer.

Comment: Which means that they probably got neglected...

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Alright, but then couldn't a question with no UPVOTED answers be styled the same as 0vote answers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show or mark that a question has no upvoted answers in the question listing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42269/show-or-mark-that-a-question-has-no-upvoted-answers-in-the-question-listing), [Indication of whether any answers have upvotes in the question list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113793/indication-of-whether-any-answers-have-upvotes-in-the-question-list)

Comment: Sure, plenty of questions have invalid answers, or no answers at all. That observation doesn't prove your claim.

Comment: Hmm.. No way to prove it :/ . Alright, I saw the dupes. You may close this.

Comment: @CodyGray - Unfortunately, I feel that's probably more accurate than we'd like to assume. I know I have a habit of looking for questions without answers indicated. It's a habit I'm trying to break, but I thihk it comes naturally to users when they figure out that early answers often get the votes, even if a "more better" answer was posted later; it's a subtle bit of gaming, IMO. No evidence, just my gut, although with data I might be able to figure it out. As an aside... Does anybody know of a site or location for SO-related bookmarklets and user scripts?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: stackapps.com?

Comment: Cool, thanks. Never knew what that site was about.